# Excel 2010 VBA: Add characters before Activecell.Copy pastes data to destination sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my 2nd thread in 2 days, trying to learn excel vba on my own.

Now i have a working code that pulls data from an active cell and paste it on to a another sheet. it works. but what i want to do is before it places the value on the destination sheet i want to add some characters. so basically instead of group of numbers (eg 12345) what i want the final value to show is similar to this (12345-A, 55455-B,) basically i want to add string suffixes to the final data.

any thoughts?

```
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: oh wait i figured it out, instead of adding the suffix "before" i did it "after" Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value + " -C"

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you realy intend to copy there, the values, the formats, the formulae... Not knowing this but only based on what's given:

Your code:

```
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

follow with something like this (one of the lines in the With block might be what you are looking for...):

```
With Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Value = "12345-A" & .Value ' this line
    .Value = .Value & "-A" ' or this line, or  whatever
End with
```

The whole thing is ugly but should work...